# How can I have the old CRT effect run properly on Kitkat?

Tags: lock-screens, xposed-framework

I'm using a rooted MT6592 phone, running Android 4.4.2 (Kitkat). It's loaded with the Xposed Framework along with Gravitybox. In Gravitybox there's a setting to have a CRT effect when the screen is locked:

*Gravitybox → Display tweaks → CRT screen off effect → CRT*

I used this effect back in the days when I had a Gingerbread device. It used to be very smooth. The CRT effect I have right now is a bit disappointing though. It's not as smooth and there seems to be a small delay after locking the screen before the CRT off effect is activated. Moreover, there's a black screen before activating the CRT effect. So, what happens is:

1. I press the lock screen button
2. The screen goes black, waits a couple of ms
3. The CRT effect starts.

[I recorded a video to clarify this behaviour.](https://vid.me/29lG)

It's very subtle but there's definitely a difference. [For comparison, this is what it used to look like.](https://youtube.com/watch?v=YhxPN47JU30) You can see that the screen does not go black before activating the CRT effect; it's activated instantly.

I followed the steps written in [this post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/themes-apps/how-to-make-crt-effect-smooth-t2201708), but that didn't help.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with fade effect triggering CRT and vice versa see this http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v3-1-5-tweak-box-android-t2554049/page127 Ads and github documentation https://github.com/GravityBox/GravityBox/issues/1139. Maybe you can fiddle around with fade effect to see if it helps

Comment: Thank you, but that does not seem to be the issue.